# How to setup a ListView

Tags: java, android

I have a game that I am making and I want to add a scoreboard or leaderboard to it so that a player can compare their scores to their friends' scores. I think i want to set it up as a list view with 2 columns and multiple rows. The first column would be the number of the row and the second column would be the player's name. I have never used a ListView before and I would like a good start in the right direction. Can someone show me how you would set this up using xml to lay out the ListView and then using Android to fill it with information? All relevent answers are appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are various score keeping apps done by different people. There source code will help you

1. [RoundTracker](https://github.com/porterhouse91/RoundTracker)
2. [KeepScore](https://github.com/nolanlawson/KeepScore)
3. [ScoreKeeper-Android](https://github.com/caspian311/ScoreKeeper-Android)

But I would recommend learning the basics of the listview and adapters. [This is a simple tutorial](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html). There are many out there, just google for 'Android listview with custom adapter'

Comment: is it possible to set a set of data to a list view? like ListView.setData(data) or something?

Comment: Data for the listview is provided by the adapter. When you update the data, you update the data given to the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() which makes the listview reload itself. Its hard to answer this as the scope is too large. You will need to work with listviews and adapters a bit to truly understand the basics.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something that is more suited for a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html) as opposed to a list view since you're looking for columns.

It's a lot like an HTML table, if you've ever used that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:layout_weight="0.1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/usernumber1" android:text="1." />
        <TextView android:layou_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/username1" android:text="user1" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

You would probably put the number of rows equal to the number of users you'd like to display in the XML, though you can probably add them dynamically in the Java code. As @blessenm mentioned, I guess there are ways to use a list view, which you would use a ListAdapter for. To me this might be easier in some ways if you're just going to have a static amount of users displayed, but if you're going for something more dynamic then you should try the ListAdapter approach.

Comment: I have edited my response to have some code in it as a simple example

Comment: thanks, it was a hard decision who to give the answer to because you both helped me a ton. Once i get enouph rep ill up you i promise